# Manually converting string to int and check if an overflow occured in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

I have the following issue - I wrote a function that takes a string and converts it to an int, but I don't know how to check if any overflow occurs. I want to return the last possible value of the integer, before the overflow ocurred. 
For example: if I have a string representation of "2147483648", I want to return 214748364 as an int, because in the next iterration an overflow will occur. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

My code is:

```
    int main () {
    string s = "2147483647";
    int num = 0, i = 0, buff = 0;
    bool isNegative = false;

    if (s[0] == '-') {
            isNegative = true;
            i++;
        }
    while (i < s.length()) {
        if (num < (INT_MAX/10)) {
            num *= 10;
        }

        if (num < INT_MAX - 10)
            num += s[i++] - '0';
        else
            break;

    }

    if (isNegative)
        num = -num;

    cout << "\nthe number is: " << num;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you show me multiple inputs and outputs that you want, and or explain what you want in more detail. There seems to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: You can check the value of `num` *before* multiplying it by 10. Catch the overflow event before it happens.

Comment: May we assume that using pre-existing functions like `std::stoi` and `strtol` that do this are disallowed?

Comment: Please don't dabble with the code posted. This isn't a real-time edit-feedback site. You need to break the loop on the first condition too.

Comment: `if (num < (INT_MAX/10)) {
            num *= 10;
        }

        if (num < INT_MAX - 10)
            num += s[i++] - '0';` does not work.  Try `"2147483640"` and `"2147483647"`  Best to revert your post to its original as commented by @Weather Vane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cope with `int` overflow, code must *prevent* it.
Simple test if `num` and `digit` are too big before attempting `num*10 + digit`

```
(num >= INT_MAX/10) && ((num > INT_MAX/10) || (digit > INT_MAX%10))
```

Usage

```
overflow = false;
while (i < s.length()) {
  int digit = s[i++] - '0';

  // Will num*10 + digit overflow?
  if ((num >= INT_MAX/10) && ((num > INT_MAX/10) || (digit > INT_MAX%10))) {
    // or break per OP's coding goal
    num = INT_MAX;
    overflow = true;
  } else {
    num *= 10;
    num += digit;
  }
}
```

OP's code also has trouble with the textual version of `INT_MIN`.

[Sample `my_atoi()`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45912/29485) that correctly returns `[INT_MIN  ... INT_MAX]`

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions:

1) Check if num<(INT_MAX/10) before multiplying num with 10 and check that num < INT_MAX - 10 before adding s[i++]. You will need to include limits.h for this.

2) After converting your string to an int, use `snprintf` to print your int back to a string and use `strcmp` to see if your strings are identical.

Comment: think you mean ` INT_MAX / 10` here ` INT_MAX - 10`

Comment: @user4581301 the answer has both, but only the `num<(INT_MAX/10)` is necessary. Adding 9 cannot then overflow `INT_MAX`.

Comment: I've tried `if (num< (INT_MAX/10))
            num *= 10;
        if (num < INT_MAX - 10 )
            num += s[i++] - '0';` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane . Couldn't grasp what that last test was for.

Comment: Any idea what I am doing wrong if this is the correct answer? I'm doing the check `num<(INT_MAX/10)` and then `num *= 10`

Comment: As INT_MAX is 2147483647 adding 9 to 2147483640 could overflow INT_MAX. Also, adding 9 to 2147483638 would not overflow INT_MAX but might later underflow INT_MIN if you find a "-" to try and convert -2147483647. I don't know why you fail with your checks, but maybe you would want to add some else that flags that you have avoided an overflow so it will be detected? What result do you get when you think things go wrong?

Comment: @Calihog you have not shown what you do if you can't take any more digits, so we don't know. But I suggest `if (num > INT_MAX/10) break;`

Comment: I have updated my code in the question. With the following string I get a result of "214748371" in the variable num.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist yes you got me, I was working from `999999999`

Comment: 214748371 is more than INT_MAX/10. So we get rather close but not all the way up to INT_MAX... If you want to be able to get all the way up to INT_MAX you will need a third solution: 1) store the previous value of num. 2) Increase num. 3) Check that num is bigger than the previous value of num.

Comment: Í don't think I'm doing the right thing. I thought that I should get 214748364 as the last value. Can I see your implementation? :(

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist *1) store the previous value of num. 2) Increase num. 3) Check that num is bigger than the previous value of num.*  But integer overflow is undefined behavior.  That's THE example given in the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for the definition of "undefined behavior":  "EXAMPLE An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow."

Comment: The reason that you get 214748371 instead of 214748364 when you was hoping for 2147483647 is that you first get 214748364 but that is not multiplied by 10 to avoid possible overflow. But then you add 7 to 214748364 which sums up to 214748371. IMHO the best thing would be to somehow detect and report overflow.

Comment: @Andrew Henle you are right that integer overflow is not defined so my example in the comment might not work. In most cases it will however when integers are represented by 2 complement numbers.

Comment: But if you really want 214748364 above it could be rather easy done with: `if (num < (INT_MAX/10)) {num *= 10; if (num < INT_MAX - 10) {num += s[i++] - '0';} else break; } else break;`. It would also be possible to get a little close with 2147483640 with `if (num <= (INT_MAX/10)) {num *= 10; if (num < INT_MAX - 10) {num += s[i++] - '0';} else break; } else break;`.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is using [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) instead of hand-crafting an inferior solution.

```
try {
    i = stoi(s);
} catch(const out_of_range& /*e*/) {
    i = numeric_limits<int>::max();
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/vsIsdC)

Comment: There is "Manually" at the topic for a reason. I don't want to use functions for this solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Calihog I'm not sure why you'd say that? Why would you try to reinvent what the standard already provides? Unless... Is this homework?